# Select rows from table such that sum of computed values of their column is less than given limit

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table myTable of the following structure:

```
id: int PRIMARY KEY
number: int
```

I'd like to randomly select 3 rows at most from myTable under the conditions:

1. Three rows at most should be selected
2. We should select id and a value calculated as `0,3*RAND()*number` converted to `INT`. The alias of the computed column is `randomValue`
3. Only rows with `randomValue>0` should be included in the result
4. Sum of `randomValues` should be less than given treshold, say 60.

So far, I've written this:

```
SELECT TOP 3 id,randomValue
            FROM(
                SELECT id, CONVERT(INT,(0.3*RAND()*number)) AS randomValue
                FROM myTable
                WHERE number>0
            ) AS D
            WHERE randomValue>0
            ORDER BY NEWID()
```

The code above selects at most 3 random rows where randomValue is greater than zero. However, I don't know how to fulfill condition 4, i.e. how to achieve that sum of randomValues in selected rows is less than 60.

This is myTable where I'm testing the solutions:

[image]

Comment: I haven't tried your query. But i don't recommend using Subquery. You have to use ROW_Number(). Sample Syntax as follows. ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ColumnName] ORDER BY ColumnValue Desc  as [CountColumn]

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
  random_values AS (
    SELECT
      id,
      CONVERT(INT,(0.3*RAND()*number)) AS randomValue
    FROM myTable
    WHERE number>0
  ),
  valid_sets AS (
    SELECT
      t1.id id1,
      t2.id id2,
      t3.id id3
    FROM random_values t1
    INNER JOIN random_values t2 ON (t2.id > t1.id)
    INNER JOIN random_values t3 ON (t3.id > t2.id)
    WHERE t1.randomValue + t2.randomValue + t3.randomValue < 60
  )
SELECT c.id,c.number
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM valid_sets ORDER BY NEWID()) a
UNPIVOT(id FOR n IN (id1,id2,id3)) b
INNER JOIN myTable c ON (b.id = c.id)
```